# DB2 Stored procedure - Add hours as input to a timestamp

Tags: datetime, stored-procedures, casting, db2

I want to create a stored procedure that has a IN_NROFHOURS as input.
Then I want to create a cursor that fetches all rows with the following condition:

```
select * from listtable where startdatetime + in_nrofhours > current timestamp
```

My questions are:

1. What is the best datatype for IN_NROFHOURS;
2. Given the datatype you suggest, how should the "where" condition be stated?

Thanks for your help, I appreciate that.

Comment: Do you expect whole hours only or are allowing fractions of hours?

Comment: Whole hours, but if it's possible to have also fractions (p.e. 22 hours and 30 mins) that would be even better.

Comment: Take a look here http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html